# List all groups and their descriptions for a specific user in Active Directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get the list of a specific user’s groups and the groups’ descriptions using PowerShell.

```
import-module activedirectory
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | select name, description
```

The description field returns blank.

Comment: Related ones: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5072996/2157640 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1458016/2157640 Did they help?

Comment: First link helped, though cannot figure out how to display the Description of the Groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617259.aspx):

> The Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership cmdlet returns a default set of ADGroup property values. To retrieve additional ADGroup properties pass the ADGroups objects produced by this cmdlet through the pipline to Get-ADGroup. Specify the additional properties required from the group objects by passing the -Properties parameter to Get-ADGroup.

So, let’s do it!

```
import-module activedirectory
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description
```

Also, in this case it should be enough to specify `name,description` instead of asterisk (`*`). If this is a performance issue, replace it. I am leaving it at asterisk because you might later change your mind about which properties you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple but effective script to get AD Group info.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties * | Select Name,GroupCategory,Description | Export-Csv D:\Test\SecurityGroups.csv
```

Just add or remove the attributes you would like to see in the Select area. To see a list of usable attributes you can do something like this:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DHCP Users' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership should work but fails if any group has a NAME containing '/' (which is a legal character in names as far as I understood the [MS AD documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776019%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)).

This forces a heavy workaround:

```
$Groups = (Get-ADUser -identity $TemplateUserName -server $TemplateUserDomain -Properties MemberOf|select memberof).MemberOf|Get-ADGroup -Server :3268
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    Write-Output $Group.Name
}
```

Notice I use a domain search for the user's properties and then a search in global catalog 
(-server :3268) for each group. Else you eventually won't get all of the user's groups or you'll get an error if any group belongs to a different domain than the user.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of groups a user is member of:

(get-aduser NameOfTheUser -properties *).memberof

Answer (score -1):

For Users

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq $username} -Properties * | select name,description
```

For Groups

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {displayname -eq $groupname} -Properties * | select name,description
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing? That would help make your answer clearer.