# How to view full group names in NET USER command

Tags: cmd, user-accounts

I'm running the command in cmd, 'net user userID /domain' and I'm getting a list of the users Group Memberships.  However, the entire Group name is not displayed in cmd window.  For example, in the attached image 'FTP Dental Officers U'.  It should read 'FTP Dental Officers Users' Does anyone know how to view the entire Group Name?

I've tried changing the Layout properties of the cmd window.  The size of the window changes but the text within it stays the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, there is no attached image as you claim, so please [edit] the question and use the *Image* button (*Ctrl+G*)! Anyway, I cannot answer your question, but maybe take a look at [`wmic`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) and perhaps the classes `Win32_UserAccount`, `Win32_Group`, `Win32_GroupUser`...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458016/get-users-non-truncated-active-directory-groups-from-command-line.  However, it looks like this is not possible strictly using "net user".

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in powershell.

```
$username = ‘userID’
$groups = (New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$($username)))")).FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().memberOf
foreach($group in $groups){Write-host "$group"}
```